# How do you overwrite the msdeploy parameter setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value when deploying from VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am able to deploy a website to a VM in AWS using VSTS. My code is hosted in git on VSTS. When I deploy using IIS Website. In the IIS Web App Deploy

In Additional Arguments I specified -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='Default Web Site\TestVSTS. But it still gets deploy to 'Default Web Site'

And on the log file on VSTS i can see the command not getting overwriten with my command. Any body having the same issue ?

Log File Command being executed by vsts : 
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='C:\vstsagent\A2_work\r3\a\temp_web_package_2238626544802922.zip' -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='Default Web Site' -enableRule:AppOffline -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule

[image: VSTS Configuration]

**Update** : Set WebSite to "Default Web Site " and Virtual Application to "TestVSTS" Still did not work. Look Below to see what I did and it did work

[image]

**Update this Work**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IIS Web App Deploy task has already included `–setParam` parameter.

Based on the parameter, you want to specify web application name, you just need to specify **Website Name** (`Default Web Site`) and **Virtual Application** (`TestVSTS`) in **IIS Web App Deploy** task.

Comment: I changed the properties as you suggested but still getting the same result. Still deploying to C:\inetpub\wwwroot instead of c:\inetpu\wwwroot\TestVSTS. I even Try to another location like C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site1\AWW and still the same. Any other sugestions ?. Thanks for answering my questions so fast.

Comment: @CodeEngine Is there TestVSTS application under Default Web Site? If not, you can create the aplication/website through IIS Web App Manage task. On the other hand, can you share detail build log on the OneDrive (Add system.debug variable and set the value to true, then start release and share this log)?

Comment: @starin chen-MSFT . Even though I set up the Virtual directory to TestVSTS on Release-> MyReleaseDefinitionName -> Edit -> Envioroment2 -> IIS WEb App Deploy  As shown on the edit of my post and saving it. It did not worked . When I click in Release -> MyReleaseDefinitionName -> Release 1 - Enviroments -> IIS Web App Deploy -> VIrtual Application was empty . Set the Virtual Application to TestVSTS and it worked. I'll show an screen shot of the fix on an update in my post